# Who are the Combine?

Tags: half-life-2

In the beginning of the game, you are simply dropped into a world, where there are robot-like creatures attacking you. Who or what are the combine? Are they a part-robot, part-human race? Are they new aliens? Are they drones made to replicate an army, or police force?

Comment: Arguably, that is part of the *point* of Half-Life 2, and the entire series even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Combine forces most frequently encountered in *Half Life 2* are, or once were, humans. At one point in the game

> you visit [Nova Prospekt](http://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Nova_Prospekt), where humans are converted into Combine Overwatch soldiers and special forces.

However, the [Combine](http://combineoverwiki.net/wiki/Combine) itself is more than just the military/police force you see in City 17 and the surrounding areas. It's

> an interdimensional empire composed of many allied and assimilated species – hence the name "Combine". Humanity has become part of the Combine.